# where does startActivityForResult deliver its Intent, and how do I collect it in the called Activity?

Tags: android

In my process I'm attempting to launch appB from appA using startActivityForResult and pass some data back and forth.
I'm probably not using it correctly because when appB launches (which it does correctly) its savedInstanceState (the onCreate param) is null.

Is that not the Bundle that the intent that I create in appA (prior to calling the appB) populates? If not where do I get that bundle?

Also, when I finish() appB which bundle do I pack with the data I want to hand back to appA in its onActivityResult handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Activity.getIntent()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getIntent%28%29).

Comment: now I'm confused about what the savedInstanceState bundle is for... is it just the Bundle I use to store my own values for when the app goes to sleep or is put in stasis for whatever reason?

Comment: it's for saving state of activity between restarts: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html#SavingActivityState

Answer (score 0):

Dr. D. There are actually at least four sets of state in your app. 1) The non view state of activity one (parent) which can be lost on a soft kill (phone rotation). 2) The non view state of activity two (child) which can be lost on a soft kill (phone rotation). 3) The state of data being passed from Activity 1 to 2 and back from activity 2 to 1. 4) The non view and view state of Activity 1 on a hard kill (user hit back button while Activity 1 has the focus.

I have sample code on 3) [here](http://sites.google.com/site/jalcomputing/home/mac-osx-android-programming-tutorial/dialog-as-activity), demonstrating pushing data using intent put extra and retrieving data using setResult and on 1), 2) [here](http://sites.google.com/site/jalcomputing/home/mac-osx-android-programming-tutorial/saving-instance-state) saving state using onSaveInstanceState.

Finally, I have some code [here](http://sites.google.com/site/jalcomputing/home/mac-osx-android-programming-tutorial/sending-serializable-as-extra) demonstrating how to encapsulate data using serializble objects and methods such as putSerializable and getSerializable.

I hope that helps,
Dr. JAL